# JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR returns null after parsing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to parse a json which has array of fields in BigQuery as follows:

`SELECT
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    STRUCT( CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(split_items,
          '$.index') AS int64) AS index,
      TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(split_items,
            '$.startTime') AS int64)) AS startTime)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(split_items, r'^"\[{|}\]"$', ''), '}') AS split_items
    FROM
      UNNEST(SPLIT(json, '},{')) AS split_items )) AS split_items
FROM (
  SELECT
   json
  FROM
    dataset:table)`

A sample json is as follows:

`"[{\"index\":0,\"startTime\":1524607204000},{\"index\":1,\"startTime\":1524607204000},{\"index\":2,\"startTime\":1524607204000}]"`

The `index` and `startTime` are both coming out as null. Is there anything wrong with this query?

Comment: It's because the JSON is an array. You need to use the `[]` operator to reference a particular entry in it. I don't have time to write an answer but hopefully that will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Below should work

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT 
      STRUCT( 
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(split_items, '$.index') AS int64) AS index,
          TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(split_items, '$.startTime') AS int64)) AS startTime
      )
    FROM (
      SELECT CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(split_items, r'\[{|}\]', ''), '}') AS split_items
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(json, '},{')) AS split_items 
    )
  ) AS split_items
FROM `dataset.table`
```

The "fix" is in below line

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(split_items, r'\[{|}\]', '')
```

You can test / play with it using your example of json as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '[{"index":0,"startTime":1524607204000},{"index":1,"startTime":1524607204000},{"index":2,"startTime":1524607204000}]' AS json
)
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT 
      STRUCT( 
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(split_items, '$.index') AS int64) AS index,
          TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(split_items, '$.startTime') AS int64)) AS startTime
      )
    FROM (
      SELECT CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(split_items, r'\[{|}\]', ''), '}') AS split_items
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(json, '},{')) AS split_items 
    )
  ) AS split_items
FROM `dataset.table`
```

with result as

```sql
Row split_items.index   split_items.startTime    
1   0                   2018-04-24 22:00:04.000 UTC  
    1                   2018-04-24 22:00:04.000 UTC  
    2                   2018-04-24 22:00:04.000 UTC
```

Comment: This is not working. The json stored in the table contains \ character. Hence, the correct input is `'"[{\\"index\\":0,\\"startTime\\":1524607204000},{\\"index\\":1,\\"startTime\\":1524607204000},{\\"index\\":2,\\"startTime\\":1524607204000}]"'` By changing the regex to `r'^"\[{|}\]"$|\\'` I was able to get the correct output. But what is really confusing is that the older query was working till recently with the same json. So I am wondering as to why it suddenly "stopped working"